# Player keeps moving when he shouldn't

Tags: unity, c#

My player in unity moves but doesn't stop when i let go of the key heres the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3();
    public CharacterController player;
    public float speed;
    public float vertSpeed;
    public float gravity;
    // Use this for initialization
     void Start(){

    }
    void Update(){
        PlayerMovement ();
    }
    void PlayerMovement(){



        if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space)) {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.up * vertSpeed * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
            if (!player.isGrounded) {
                movement.y = movement.y - gravity * Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.A)) { // left
            movement.x = movement.x - speed * Time.deltaTime;

        } else if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.D)) {// goes right 
            movement.x = movement.x + speed * Time.deltaTime;
        }



        player.Move ((movement * speed) * (Time.deltaTime));
    }

}
```

Comment: mark this as answered instead of changing the title.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Underneath the answer's vote buttons should be a tick. Just press that.

Comment: I'm on my phone atm I'll be sure to do it soon

Comment: that would explain the badge for rollbacks haha, thanks :) ill be sure to use this.

Answer (score 3):

As you are using `CharacterController`component you don't need to check which individual button pressed. By checking horizontal axis you can get if you are pressing left/A or right/D at once. Also a "Jump" button is defined for Space button in Unity.

Your `PlayerMovement()` should be like:

```
void PlayerMovement()
{
    if (player.isGrounded)
    {
        movement = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, 0);
        movement = transform.TransformDirection(movement);
        movement *= speed;
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            movement.y = vertSpeed;

    }
    movement.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    player.Move(movement * Time.deltaTime);
}
```